# Spotipy Function which returns whether a playlist is public or private given the link?

Tags: python, spotipy

Is there a similar function of spotipy? Why does it happen that inserting the link of a private playlist generates a 404 error. Solutions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you would get a 404, so if you want to post the exact error message that spotipy gives you then we can look through it. more than likely it's because of a lack of scope or authentication.

when you get a playlist, there's key:value that says "public: true" or "public: false"

if you're working in a limited scope, so you get the 404 you can simply say

```
try:
    <function to grab a playlist>

except <the error that spotipy calls for the 404>:
    <code when you get the 404>
```